# F# - Using File.ReadAllLines how is it posible to get a string without new lines

Tags: list, types, f#, functional-programming

The problem is that I have a string like:

```
public class MyFirstJavaProgram {

   public static void main ( String []args ) {
      System.out.println ( "Hello World" ); 
   }
}
```

When I try to get a string list like:

```
 ["public";"class";"MyFirstJavaProgram";...;"(";""Hello World"";")";"...]
```

Im getting

```
["public class MyFirstJavaProgram {"; "";
 "   public static void main ( String []args) {";
 "      System.out.println("Hello World"); "; "   }"; "}"]
```

How can i remove those white spaces.

Comment: Use `trim` for this sort of thing - it removes whitespace

Comment: In your expected output you state you expected "public" and "class" as separated elements, but "Hello World" all together. Could you expand on this? It's because of the quotes? Can you specify the full output?

Comment: I was trying to make tokens of the string list using types of F# but i think Im going to use fsyacc and fslex instead..... And some of the tokens are strings   .

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in some lines, the way to go is `filter`:

```
File.ReadAllLines(...)
|> Seq.filter (not << String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace)
```

Then, you can split all lines:

```
|> Seq.collect (fun line -> line.Split([| " " |], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

`RemoveEmptyEntries` will remove empty lines and leading/trailing whitespace. So `filter`ing is not needed anymore and no `trim`ming is neccessary.

Note that this is not a proper Java tokenizer though, e.g. `main(` won't be split into `main` and `(` but `"Hello World"` will be split into `"Hello` and `World"`.

For doing proper Java parsing, look for a library.
<sub>Note that asking for and recommending libraries is not appropriate on StackOverflow. [SoftwareRecommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) might be able to help.</sub>

Comment: Actually I was wrong, I think the OP is implying they want the different constructs split apart.

Comment: Note is should be `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` with a capital `S`!

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample output in the original question, I think the closest simple solution would be:

```
File.ReadAllText("MyFirstJavaProgram.java").Split([|' '; '\n'|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 
|> Array.map (fun s -> s.Trim())
```

However, this will not treat the string "Hello World" as one entry in the array.  For that, you would need to use a proper tokenization algorithm.